# Convert a binary min-heap to a binary search tree in place

Tags: algorithm, heap, binary-search-tree

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert a maximum heap to a binary search tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4966014/convert-a-maximum-heap-to-a-binary-search-tree)

**Convert a min-heap into a binary search tree as efficiently as possible without using additional space. (Recursion is allowed).**

This question has been driving me crazy. There *must* be a way to use the min-heap property to do this more efficiently than brute force. For instance, given this min-heap:

```
    [1, 7, 6, 9, 8, 21, 15] =

                1
             /     \  
           7        6
          / \      / \
         9   8   21   15
```

We know immediately that by definition, the root is going to be the leftmost node in our binary search tree. We also know that the right child of any node in the min-heap does not violate the BST property (parent.right > parent).

How can we exploit these facts to efficiently create a BST in-place?

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4966014/convert-a-maximum-heap-to-a-binary-search-tree